# Redirects problems in wordpress behind nginx proxy

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, wordpress-rest-api

Docker-compose wordpress (I am using https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress this image):

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  asd-wordpress:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/asd/asd-wordpress:latest 
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}
      - WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA=

          define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://asd.com/wp-site' );

          define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://asd.com/wp-site' );
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - mynet
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
      - "db-srv:$HOST_DB"

networks:
  mynet:
volumes:
  wordpress:
```

Nginx config:

```
  location ^~ /wp-site/ {
    include conf.d/common/maintenance_conditions.conf;

    #request headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

    proxy_pass    http://wp_upstream/;
    proxy_no_cache 1;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht { # Deny access to .htaccess, .htpassword 
        deny all;
  }
```

What works fine:

- http://asd.com/wp-site/ -> opens a website
- http://asd.com/wp-site/wp-admin -> opens login page after redirecting to http://asd.com/wp-site/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwp_upstream%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 -> after logging in it redirects to correct http://asd.com/wp-site/wp-admin/ page

I can open every page on wordpress.
What does not work properly:

- http://asd.com/wp-site/wp-admin/options-general.php - opens just fine, but if I try to submit "Save changes" button it redirects to wrong page http://asd.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true (no /wp-site/ in url). If I add /wp-site/ to url manually settings are saved correctly and I am redirected to correct page again.

My wordpress structure:

```
#/var/www/html/
total 252K
drwxr-xr-x.  6   33 tape   80 Jan 17 19:27 wp-content
drwxr-xr-x.  5   33 tape 4.0K Jan 17 19:13 .
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape  539 Jan 17 19:10 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 5.5K Jan 17 19:09 wp-config.php
drwx-----x.  3 root root   19 Jan 17 19:09 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 5.4K Jan 12 01:26 wp-config-docker.php
drwxr-xr-x. 27   33 tape  12K Dec  6 17:25 wp-includes
drwxr-xr-x.  9   33 tape 4.0K Dec  6 17:25 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 3.0K Nov 15 18:47 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape  26K Oct 10 16:05 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 3.1K Sep 30 09:39 xmlrpc.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape  50K Sep 30 00:01 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 8.4K Sep 16 08:50 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 3.9K Jul 16  2023 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 7.3K Jul  5  2023 readme.html
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 4.8K Jun 22  2023 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape  34K Jun 19  2023 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 2.3K Jun 14  2023 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 5.6K May 30  2023 wp-cron.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 7.1K May 12  2023 wp-activate.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape  20K Jan  1  2023 license.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape 2.5K Nov 26  2022 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape  405 Feb  6  2020 index.php
-rw-r--r--.  1   33 tape  351 Feb  6  2020 wp-blog-header.php
```

My .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wp-site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp-site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

There is also problem with different endpoints like http://asd.com/wp-site/graphql -> it does not work (500 Internal error with error: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.) but http://asd.com/wp-site/?graphql=true works fine.